# How to create a universal procedural texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

[image]

Outlined above is the node setup I used to create a battered metal material which I have succeeded to make for most of the part and said material's output can be seen below on the sphere.

[image]

However, things start to get screwy when the same material is applied on a plane whose rotation is 0 and 90 degrees accordingly as seen below.

[image]

And the problem gets weirder when said plane is rotated. As it is rotated, theoretically the texture should be uniform and must be indentations, but instead are partly indentations and partly risen as seen below.

[image]

Now my question is four fold,[A] why is this happening?[B] How do I fix it?[C] Currently I am using the bottom (Black - White) color ramp to control the size of the indentation / holes, is there a better way of doing this? And [D] can this node setup be baked into texture files to follow a Metallic - Roughness workflow?

Enclosed below is the blend file in case you'tr having a tough time replicating the node setup.

[image]

Comment: If you unwrap it and use the UV texture coordinate, instead of object, does that improve it?

Comment: @PlanetAlexanderProjects Just tried your suggestion, and no it doesn't...also, I can't use UV coordinates because that would create the issue of seams in the texture and it would no longer be seamless PS : both models are already unwrapped.